# "go get golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15" fails on undefined identifiers

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a program dependent upon gcimporter15 for Go, and so I'm using the command "go get golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15", but it fails with the error:

```
# golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15
../../go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15/bexport.go:557: undefined: constant.ToFloat
../../go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15/gcimporter.go:396: pkg.SetName undefined (type *types.Package has no field or method SetName)
```

That appears to me that there is an error within gcimporter itself, but that doesn't make sense that I would get this when it doesn't appear that others are. Why isn't it working?

I'm using Go 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

The [godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15) tells that the package `gcimporter` is deprecated and this package will be deleted in October 2017. And this new code should be used: [golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata](https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata) instead of `gcimporter` .

So, what you have to do is:

```
$ go get godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata
```

**PS:** Tested within `Ubuntu 16.04 64bit` and `go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64` without any issues.

Test:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    gcexportdata "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata"
)
func main() {
    filename, path := gcexportdata.Find("fmt", "")
    fmt.Println(filename, path)
}
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/linux_amd64/fmt.a fmt
```

Answer (score 0):

Its bad but seems there is a mismatch between the `gcimporter15` and `go-1.5`. I faced the same problem and looked at `go-1.5` code in file `src/go/constant/value.go` and there is no `ToFloat()` function in the `constant` package.

As @nexus66 says, the `gcimporter` is deprecated. So, I don't expect them to fix this. If you are using this package directly, its better to move on to the recommended `gcexportdata` package. If you are using a third party library which is in turn using `gcimporter`, may be you should upgrade to `go-1.7`. That's what I did and things worked fine.